# Can't insert into std::list?

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to insert values into a std::list called in a void. The void will insert values into the list to be used when it's called from another function, but when I try to insert values into the list with .push_back , .Insert or .Add, I get the following error: [image: I get the following error]

Here's my code:

```
void pb(std::list<unsigned long long int> primeFactorisation(unsigned long long int), int n)
{
    for (int i=n; i<n; i++)
    {
        primeFactorisation.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, this is a standard list?

Comment: Please no images of text.

Comment: I can't change the list itself. It's part of a university assignment and the specification outlines that I have to use that exact list with those parameters.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are misunderstanding the assignment. It may be that you are expected to make a function with the signature `std::list<unsigned long long int> primeFactorisation(unsigned long long int)`.

Comment: `void pb(std::list<unsigned long long int>& primeFactorisation, int n)` should help

Answer (score 6):

In

```
void pb(std::list<unsigned long long int> primeFactorisation(unsigned long long int), int n)
```

your first parameter

```
std::list<unsigned long long int> primeFactorisation(unsigned long long int)
```

declares a function, not a `std::list` parameter.  You need

```
void pb(std::list<unsigned long long int>& primeFactorisation, int n)
```

for `pb` to work correctly (note that `primeFactorisation` needs to be passed by reference for it to modify the list passed from the call site).

---

You also have an issue with your for loop.

```
for (int i=n; i<n; i++)
```

will never run as `i == n` in the first loop so `i < n` will be `false` before you even start.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Good call.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
void pb(std::list<unsigned long long int>& primeFactorisation, int n)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        primeFactorisation.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Your initial version is almost formatted to accept a function called `primeFactorisation` due to the inclusion of `(unsigned long long int)`.

As @FrançoisAndrieux points out, the list needs to be passed by reference or pointer, or a temporary copy will be made and none of your `push_back()`s will affect the original list passed by the caller.

Also, you're starting your for loop at a point where it will never execute.

```
for(int i=n;i<n;i++)
```

Could be rephrased as:

```
i=n;  // ok
is i < n? // nope, since you just set i=n.
```

Instead, set `i=0` in the first part of the `for`.

Comment: The parameter is named `primeFactorisation` but it could just as well be named `winningLottoNumbers` I guess.